# Prediction option put and call, FFT Method in python

Tags: python, fft, call, put, prediction

I try to make prediction of option put and call with the FFT method, but i got some problem in my python code and i don't know what i have to modify. Can you help me ?

```
options = pd.read_csv("/Users/Abenaya/Documents/relevantoptions2",sep =',',header = 0)

print(options)

x=[]
for i in range (1,415):
 x.append(i)

p1 =sp.polyfit(x, np.array(options.today_sp_price.iloc[1:415,]), 3)
xx =range(1,506)
pp1 =np.polyval(p1, xx)
plt.plot(xx, options.iloc[1:506,3])
plt.hold()
plt.plot(xx, pp1)
plt.xlabel('time(days)')
plt.ylabel('stock price')
plt.title('least squares vs. stock price')
plt.savefig('plot.pdf')
```

I have this problem:    given_len=len(right)))

ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 12: given 414

In the data, i have 12 columns, but i just want to work on the 3rd column and on each lines of this column.
The data points didn't appear on the graphic.

Comment: x = list(range (1,415)) is a nicer way to make x, first.

What does "np.array(options.today_sp_price.iloc[1:415,]), 3)" look like? Is it a numpy array of len 414?

Comment: I still have the same problem as before. Yes, exactly, and the 3 at the end means that we'll do the least square method in the third degree

Comment: What has the code you showed us to do with FFT?  Further, the [call] and the [put] tags do not mean what apparently you think.